# Iterated Integral, polynomial change of variable (?)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I´m not sure how to integrate this, should I do a change of variables (we haven't seen it yet in our course)? Is there any other way?

> $$ \int_0^2\int_0^1 (x+y)^8 dx dy $$

I'm rather interested in the general case, but this is the integral that motivated the question.

EDIT:
I know expanding this using the binomial theorem works. However I don't think this is the intent of the exercise. As I said, I want to know about some technique to use in more general cases.

Comment: Consider y to be constant in the inner integral and work your way outward.

Comment: For this particular integral, the easiest way is to expand $(x+y)^8$, and then you have a sum of 9 products of two simple 1D integrals $\int_0^2x^8dx\int_0^1dy+8\int_0^2x^7dx\int_0^1ydy+...$

Comment: I didn't want to do that. Also, I think this is supposed to invite us to use some technique.

Comment: I do not understand the scope of this question. You do now want to perform a binomial expansion, since it involves a lot of terms. You do not want to perform a change of variables, since you haven't seen yet, so what are you likely to accept from us?

Comment: Well, I don't know, which is why I ask. If a change of variable is the standard approach, then I suppose it answers my question. Again, I don't know of another way, am asking whether there's one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can evaluate the first integral
$$
\int_0^1(x+y)^8dx
$$
with the substitution $x+y=t \quad \rightarrow \quad dx=dt$
so, the integral becomes:
$$
\int_{y}^{1+y}t^8dt=\frac{1}{9}\left[ (1+y)^9-y^9\right]
$$
and the second integration becomes:
$$
\frac{1}{9}\left[\int_0^2 (1+y)^9dy-\int_0^2y^9dy\right]
$$

that is not difficult to solve using an analogous substitution for the first integral.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{1}(x+y)^8\,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{2}\left. \frac{(x+y)^9}{9}\right|_{x=0}^{x=1}\,dy =\frac{1}{9}\int_{0}^{2}\left[(y+1)^9-y^9\right]\,dy$$
hence $I= \color{red}{\large\frac{3^{10}-2^{10}-1}{90}}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$I=\sum_{k=0}^8\binom{8}{k}\int_0^2x^kdx \int_0^1y^{8-k}dy$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^8\binom{8}{k}\frac{2^{k+1}}{k+1}\frac{1}{9-k}$$